# Получить индекс перечисления

Tags: c#, enum

Имеется перечисление вида:

```
enum MyControls: ulong { elementONE = 18410924985427079801, elementTWO = 88410924985427079804, elementF = 58410924985427079802};
```

Так же имеется массив, который инициилизируется при старте так:

```
MyClass[] mc1 = new MyClass[Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyControls)).Length];
```

экземпляры myclass добавляются и соответствуют тому же порядку, что описан в mycontrols.

Можно ли как то получить доступ к элементам такого массива, используя запись вида `mc1[MyControls.elementF]`. ( index elementF == 2)

Интересуют любые способы получения индекса в данном перечисление!

Можно было бы завести дополнительное перечисление, например

```
enum MyControlsNames = {elementONE, elementTWO, elementF }
```

и свободно писать `mc1[MyControlsNames.elementF]`, но интересует 1й способ.

Благодарю за ответы!

Comment: @Grundy Вот эта [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/232677) была отклонена. Разве "править(1)" не было видно? Это баг?

Comment: @0xdb, я вполне мог начать редактировать раньше, а закончить позже. А также, похоже что в то время редактировал не я, а автор вопроса.

Comment: @0xdb, так-то лока вообще нет.

Answer (score 3):

Сделайте не массив, а Dictionary

```
var mc1 = new Dictionary<MyControls,MyClass>();
mc1.Add(MyControls.elementF, new MyClass(MyControls.elementF));
```

Comment: Думаю, это то, что нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Можно перегрузить индексатор

```
class MyClass {

    public int this[ulong i]
    {
        get
        {
            // ваш код извлечения необходимой записи
        }
    }
}
```

Почитать про перегрузку индексаторов можно [тут](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level6/6_3.php) и [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.10.php).

Answer (score 0):

Приведите к типу хранения, напишите `(byte)MyEnumVariant` - выводит индекс

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]